# How to resolve sftp:// or smb:// directories on Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, sftp

I have noticed that whenever you "mount" a network share or location using graphical tools like Thunar or Nautilus, you get a nice `sftp://path/to/file` kind of url to files and directories alike, however if I try to e.g. `cat 'sftp://home/remote/a-file'` I obviously get a file not found error, but I remember that back in the days you could just head to `/run/1000/gvfs/` and find the mount points of such resources; why doesn't it work anymore? and more important: how can I resolve those uris or access those resources without actually having to manually mount them or fiddling with fstab?

I have tried inspecting the output of `mount` to see if they are around somewhere without any luck.